# Show that for a rational $a$ there is a finite amount of rationals $\frac{p}{q} \neq a$ such that $|a - \frac{p}{q}| < \frac{1}{q^2}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, approximation

I want to shot that there for rational number $a \in \mathbb{Q}$, there is a finite amount of rational numbers $\frac{p}{q} \neq a$ such that $|a - \frac{p}{q}| < \frac{1}{q^2}$.

I know that for a irrational number $\alpha$, there are infinite such rationals, and it follows as a correlation from Dirichlet's approximation theorem.

However, I am not sure how it fails when $a$ is rational.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: According classical Dirichlet's theorem if $a$ is irrational then there are infinitely many rationals $\frac pq$ such that $|a - \frac{p}{q}| < \frac{1}{q^2}$. The asked problem is a simple corollary of this fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a=m/n$. Then
$$\left|a-\frac pq\right|=\left|\frac mn-\frac pq\right|=\frac{|mq-np|}{nq}.$$
Since this is a nonnegative integer over $nq$, it is either $0$ or $\geq \frac{1}{nq}$. Can you finish from here?

Comment: I am not exactly sure, but it has something to do with the fact that there is only a finite amount of naturals $q$ such that $ q \le n$,  right?

Comment: @GabiG exactly. For large $q$, this $1/nq>1/q^2$.